# check in policies in TFS using Visual studio 11 preview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I want to configure check in policies for my Team project using visual studio 11 preview and TFS explorer. I know how to do it in visual studio by right clicking Team project and then team project settings and then configure check in policies but In visual studio 11, things has changed. Please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the home page of the new team explorer the last option should be "Settings".  When you click on that you will navigate to the settings page in team explorer and from there you can access the team project settings.